# jQuery wrap span around text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have the following

```
<div><span class="myspan">hello</span> this text has no span </div>
```

In jQuery, how can I wrap a `div` or span around the "this text has no span" text?

Comment: if i were you i would mark @Vision as answer.any pain must be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your current example here is my one line solution:

```
$("div span").detach().prependTo($("div").contents().wrap("<span />").end());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/awwTA/

Comment: this is why i am lover of jquery!

Comment: @Behnam Esmaili Yes and no, could give headaches to maintain but this example is just nice

Comment: there is nothing more valuable than time.and jquery saves my time.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be the best solution but can help you...

```
<div id="myDiv"><span class="myspan">hello</span> this text has no span </div>

var div = $('div#myDiv');
var span = $('span.myspan');
div.remove(span);
div.html($('<span></span>').text(div.text()));
```

I guess you have the idea what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any text (nodeType:3) element in the parent div and then wrap each text in another div. See below example:

```js
$('#myDiv').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrapAll("<div class='red' />");
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"><span class="myspan">Hello</span> this text has no span </div>
```